# How to return BadRequest if payload contains unexpected fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I'm trying to make PATCH operation, that should fail if request body contains fields that are not specified in contract. For example, if I call this method:

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> PatchResource(
    [FromRoute][Required] Guid id,
    [FromBody][Required] PatchRequest request) {/* whatever */}
```

where `PatchRequest` is

```
public class PatchRequest
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Address { get; }
    public PatchRequest(string name, string address) { Name = name; Address = address; }
}
```

I would like to return `400 (Bad Request)`, possibly with explanation, if I get request body like this

```
{
  "name": "Adam",
  "address" "NY City",
  "additional": true
}
```

I want to return

> 400 (Bad Request) - Didn't expect property 'additional'

I know that if I set custom serializer on `PatchRequest` with `MissingMemberHandling` set to `Error` I can easily get `500 (Internal Server Error)` in this case by throwing exception, but it wouldn't make sense, because it's request that is at fault here, not server.

Comment: This article might help you! - https://blog.cloudhub360.com/returning-400-bad-request-from-invalid-model-states-in-asp-net-94275fdfd2a0

Comment: Sadly, the article relates to different problem. It takes care of invalid Model, by default, a request containing unspecified property will result in valid Model, so I can't really use anything that's suggested there

Comment: That's not a patch. That's just a partial JSON object, which is frankly useless anyways. See: http://jsonpatch.com/.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes, it is not JSON Patch, it is still HTTP patch, RFC 5789 (PATCH method) does not specify how is "description of changes" supposed to look like, and RFC 6902 (one for JSON Patch) says 'it is suitable for use with the HTTP PATCH method. The "application/json-patch+json" media type is used to identify such patch documents.', it is not the only compliant way to implement it (and in my use case, it is an overkill given I only support `replace` operation in it)

Comment: Well, regardless, there's no facility in HTTP patch to restrict what may or may not be sent. Even if such existed, it would be part of a standard body format like JSON Patch, and your decidedly going non-standard here. However, since you're responsible for actually applying the changes manually (because you're not using something like JSON Patch which has native support in ASP.NET Core), you can choose to handle extraneous items however you like, as part of that manual process.

Comment: You are right, I should accept any properly formatted document (so in this case, there my patch document is simple JSON, any valid JSON). At first I understood this excerpt from RFC 5789 "The definition of badly formatted depends on the patch document chosen." as "definition depends on API contract", hence my reasoning for 400 (Bad Request), however, the only thing that changes, is that I need to use 422 (Unprocessable Entity) instead, because literally any other operation than replacing values given in contract, will cause my entity to end up in invalid state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `PatchRequest` model, add a JsonExtensionsData property

```
public class PatchRequest
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Address { get; }
    public PatchRequest(string name, string address) { Name = name; Address = address; }

    // extra fields
    [JsonExtensionData]
    private IDictionary<string, JToken> _extraStuff;
}
```

Then in your controller if _extraStuff is not empty you have received additional fields.

Comment: It looks like it will work, though it requires me to set it on all request model classes, and checks on all methods. Would you happen to have an idea how to make it more convenient, generic solution? (i.e. as attribute on method, I suppose that would be perfect)

Comment: You could make it part of a base class and have your models all inherit from it. Beyond that I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

The following functionality will return you exactly which properties are different from the defined object in `FromBody`

Create a class, e.g. `ValidationBase`

In the class, create a method to validate your object, e.g. `ValidateModel()`

`ValidateModel()` - contains the entire logic of your validation

**Controller: (Endpoint)**

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> PatchResource([FromRoute][Required] Guid id, 
[FromBody][Required] PatchRequest request)
{
    string body;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
    {
        body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    validator = new ValidationBase();
    string resultValidation = validator.ValidateObject(body, new PatchRequest());

    if (resultValidation.Length != 0)
    {
        return BadRequest(new { error_message = resultValidation });
    }

    // Content endpoint

    return Json(response);
}
```

**ValidationBase:**

```
public class ValidationBase
{

    public string ValidateObject(string json, object obj)
    {
        var dictJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
        var listParameterInJSON = dictJSON.Keys.ToHashSet<string>();
        listParameterInJSON.ToList().ForEach(x => x = x.ToLower());

        var jsonObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        var dictObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonObj);
        var listParameterInObj = dictObj.Keys.ToList();

        listParameterInObj = listParameterInObj.ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower());
        listParameterInObj.ToHashSet<string>();

        var fields = listParameterInJSON.Except(listParameterInObj);

        if (fields.ToList().Count == 0) return "";

        var result = "Didn't expect property ";

        foreach (var item in fields)
        {
            result += "'" + item + "'" + " ";
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how does this code report erroneous properties?

Comment: It doesn't help at all, a request containing unspecified property in body will result in valid Model because the additional property is simply discarded.

Comment: @CodeCaster I rebuilt the answer. Now it returns specific fields that are not in the object

Comment: @Arion If another simpler solution does not work then it will return you unnecessary fields in JSON